"No infinite discrete subspace" vs "No infinite pairwise disjoint family of opens"
What is the relationship between the two properties (for a topological space $X$)

$A$: "$X$ has no infinite family of pairwise disjoint open subsets"
$B$: "$X$ has no infinite discrete subspace"

We know that $B$ must imply $A$, by the discussion below, but there's probably a simple proof that I'm missing. My guess is that under mild conditions $A$ implies $B$ too, but I have no idea what these mild conditions should be, or what a counterexample might look like in general.
Now, for some motivation:

Earlier today on the Category Theory Zulip, Peva Blanchard asked whether we could classify for which spaces $X$ the presheaf of bounded real valued functions on $X$ is actually a sheaf.
It's not hard to see that if $X$ has a pairwise disjoint infinite family of opens $\{ U_\alpha \}$, then the presheaf of bounded functions cannot be a sheaf. Indeed, pick a countable subfamily $\{ U_n \}$ and define the function $f : \bigcup U_n \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f \upharpoonright_{U_n} = n$. This is locally bounded, in the sense that it's bounded on each fixed $U_k$, but of course the complete function is not bounded.
This feels close to sufficient, and indeed some quick googling for an "antichain condition in the lattice of opens" brings up Jean Goubault-Larrecq's Spaces with No Infinite Discrete Subspace, which mentions a result from Stone's Hereditarily Compact Spaces that shows the following are equivalent for a space $X$:

For every subspace $A \subseteq X$, for every open cover of $A$, there's a finite subcover whose intersection is dense in $A$
For every subspace $A \subseteq X$, every continuous real valued function on $A$ is bounded
$X$ has no infinite discrete subspace

So then it seems like the correct condition for the bounded functions to form a sheaf is "there is no infinite discrete subspace", rather than my initial conjecture of "there is no infinite family of pairwise disjoint opens".
Of course, these seem like closely related conditions...
This hopefully motivates my question, which I could possibly answer myself if I had more time, but which someone else will almost certainly see immediately.

Any insight is appreciated ^_^

By "discrete subspace" you mean a subspace which is discrete in its subspace topology, right? Well then if there is an infinite family as in A, you select one element $x_U$ from each of those pairwise disjoint open subsets $U$; then the set ${x_U}$ is an infinite discrete subspace. That might be the "simple proof [you are] missing" for B $\implies$ A.

A counterexample to A $\implies$ B is: Take any infinite space $X$ with one special element $x_0$, and call a subset of $X$ open iff it is empty or contains $x_0$. Then the subspace $X\setminus {x_0}$ of $X$ is discrete in its subspace topology.

A mild condition, which guarantees equivalence, is Hausdorff: it is well-known that an infinite Hausdorff space contains an infinite family of pairwise disjoint open sets. Hence, A and B are equivalent to finiteness of $X$.

Here's a T1 counterexample to A $\implies B$: Let $X$ consist of two infinite sets of points $x_n$ and $y_n$, and call a subset of $X$ open iff (it is either empty or contains all but finitely many of the $y_n$). Then the subspace consisting of all $x_n$ is discrete in its subspace topology. -- So, together with @Ulli's remark that T2 is enough (backed up by https://math.stackexchange.com/q/547517/96384), we know equivalence starts somewhere between T1 and T2. I wonder if R1 is enough.

@TorstenSchoeneberg -- If you assembled these comments into an answer, I would already be happy to accept it! Of course, that goes doubly if you're enjoying thinking about this R1 property (which I've never heard of, haha)

The cocountable topology on uncountable set is another $T_1$-counterexample.

To summarize and amend comments:
For $R_1$ (in particular, Hausdorff) spaces, the conditions are equivalent. But examples for $A \not \Rightarrow B$ exist among spaces which satisfy $T_1$, or weaker separation axioms (cf. Wikipedia for the terminology of separation axioms $T_n$ and $R_n$).

I. The implication $B \implies A$ holds in any topological space $X$ by the following straightforward proof (of $\neg A \implies \neg B$):
If $U_i$, $i\in I$ are an infinite family of mutually disjoint open (w.l.o.g non-empty) subsets, then for each $i$ pick an $x_i \in U_i$. The subset $\{x_i: i \in I\} \subset X$ is infinite, and discrete in its subspace topology.

II. Here are two examples, both of which are $T_1$ (and hence $T_0$ and $R_0$), where $A \not \Rightarrow B$. Note that in both of them, there is not even a single pair of non-empty open subsets with nontrivial intersection.
a) Let $X$ consist of two infinite sets of points $x_n$ and $y_n$, and call a subset of $X$ open iff it is either empty or contains all but finitely many of the $y_n$. Then the subspace consisting of all $x_n$ is discrete in its subspace topology.
b) (Suggested by user Ulli in a comment:) Take an uncountable set $X$ and endow it with the co-countable topology. Then every countable subset of $X$ is discrete in its subspace topology.

III. As user Ulli points out in a comment, $A \implies B$ does hold in every Hausdorff (i.e. $T_2$) space. That is because a Hausdorff space which satisfies $A$ must be finite, cf. Infinite disjoint class of open subsets in an infinite Hausdorff space.

IV. I claim that more generally, $A \implies B$ for all $R_1$ spaces.
Proof: Let $X$ be $R_1$ and satisfy $A$. Then its Kolmogorov quotient $KQ(X)$ also satisfies $A$ (because if there were an infinite family of mutually disjoint open sets in it, their preimages in $X$ would also be an infinite family of mutually disjoint open sets). But the Kolmogorov quotient of an $R_1$ space is Hausdorff, so by III, $KQ(X)$ is finite. That is, $X$ is the union of finitely many equivalence classes $X_1, ... X_n$, which are clopen, and the open subsets (also, the closed subsets) of $X$ are exactly the unions $\bigcup_{i \in S} X_i$, with $S$ the subsets of $\{1, ..., n\}$. Any discrete subspace of this cannot contain more than one point from each $X_i$, hence must be finite.

With the nice idea using the Kolmogorov quotient in the above proof of IV, it can actually be improved to:
Let $(X, \tau)$ be $R_1$ satisfying condition A. Then $\tau$ is finite.
[Let $\lambda: X \rightarrow KQ(X)$ be the canonical map. The map $\tau \rightarrow {V: V \text{ open in } KQ(X)}, U \mapsto \lambda(U)$ is easily seen to be bijective. Now, as Torsten Schoeneberg argued, A implies that $KG(X)$ is finite, hence $\tau$ is finite.]

Incredible! Thanks for thinking so hard about this, and for summarizing the comments so nicely ^_^
